# Using .htaccess to block URL containing a keyword only if it is not containing another keyword

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is an odd situation, someone is hammering our servers with http requests trying to access different TinyMCE based editors. I want to block any URL containing the keyword `editor` but we have valid working URLs containing the same word ... For example `letter-from-editor.html` or `editorial-board.html`

Is there a way using .htaccess I can contain any URL containing the keyword `editor` only if it doesn't contain the keyword `html` ?

This is what I am trying right now that blocks `editor` only

```
RewriteRule (^|/)editor(/|$) - [F,L]
```

I really searched and I couldn't find a way around it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a simple condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !html
RewriteRule (^|/)editor(/|$) - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With that, you block only link that do not exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (^|/)editor(/|$) - [F,L]
```